# How to resolve gargle error when reading a Google sheet into R?

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to read a Google sheet in RStudio and even though the authentication goes through without a hitch, I keep getting a gargle error:

```
✖ Request failed [503]. Retry 1 happens in 1.9 seconds ...
Error in `gargle::response_process()`:
! Client error: (400) INVALID_ARGUMENT
• Client specified an invalid argument. Check error
 message and error details for more information.
• Request contains an invalid argument.

Backtrace: 
1. googlesheets4::read_sheet("sheet link")
2. googlesheets4:::get_cells(...)
3. googlesheets4::gs4_get(ssid)
4. googlesheets4:::gs4_get_impl_(as_sheets_id(ss))
5. gargle::response_process(raw_resp)
```

Here is my initial code:

```
library(googlesheets4)
read_sheet("sheet link")

Is it OK to cache OAuth access credentials in the folder
~/Library/Caches/gargle between R sessions?

1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1
The httpuv package enables a nicer Google auth experience,
in many cases.
It doesn't seem to be installed.
Would you like to install it now?

1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1
```

I've explored different documentation online but can't seem to find a solution.